# Deletion of first line in questions

Tags: support, status-bydesign, questions

I've noticed that when I make the first line of my post

> Hi Superuser,

or

> Hello Superuser,

It auto-deletes it.

If it is anything else (maybe a few more variants of this exist), it will not delete. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 7):

Salutations are [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989), because posts do not need to have salutations. You can see the full regex used to select salutations to remove in the linked meta SO post.

Comment: Although itdoesntwork didn't ask why, I think it makes sense to mention that StackExchange sites are about building knowledge bases, not having conversations. So greetings are unnecessary cruft.